# Один ScrollBar для двух RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли сделать один `ScrollBar`, который будет прокручивать два `RichTextBox`? `RichTextBox1` - это сам текст, а `RichTextBox2` пометки/комментарии к выбранной строке в `RichTextBox1`.

Comment: Нужно синхронно со скроллбаром из одного `richTextBox` прокручивать текст в другом? или нужен отдельный элемент скролл на два `richTextBox`?

Comment: Нужно синхронно со скроллбаром из одного richTextBox прокручивать текст в другом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте класс `SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox`, который наследуется от `RichTextBox` и переопределите метод `WndProc`:

```
public class SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
{
    public event vScrollEventHandler vScroll;
    public delegate void vScrollEventHandler(System.Windows.Forms.Message message);

    public const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)
    {
        if (msg.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
        {
            if (vScroll != null)
            {
                vScroll(msg);
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }

    public void PubWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
}
```

Дальше измените в дизайнере формы тип своих `richTextBox` на `SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox`. 
В объявлении:

```
private SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox richTextBox1;
private SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox richTextBox2;
```

В инициализации:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   ...
   this.richTextBox1 = new SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox();
   this.richTextBox2 = new SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox();
   ...
}
```

и в созданном событии `vScroll` добавьте:

```
private void richTextBox1_vScroll(Message message)
{
    message.HWnd = richTextBox2.Handle;
    richTextBox2.PubWndProc(ref message);
}
```

Оригинал: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/199253/WebControls/

Comment: Коротко добавлю:  
  1. Поясню за последний пример кода с событием. Данное событие vScroll отличается от системного Vscroll. Vscroll принимает параметры (object sender, EventArgs e), в то время как vScroll только Message.   
Если вы добавляете событие через конструктор, через панель событий, то vScroll у вас появиться только после того, как вы измените тип вашего элемента с простого RichTextBox на SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox.
  2. Чтобы оба SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox  листались, вам надо вручную двигать по ScrollBar, колесо мыши в данном примере не работает.